Run Ktlint on a specific file
I have a Kotlin project configured with Ktlint. I am executing the command ./gradlew ktlintCheck to get reports from my code according to my .editorconfig file configured. Nonetheless, I would like to execute the ktlintCheck only over my changed files detected from git diff, but it is not working. Here is my script:
#!/bin/bash

BASE_BRANCH="main"

MODIFIED_FILES=$(git diff --name-only "$BASE_BRANCH" -- '*.kt')

if [ -n "$MODIFIED_FILES" ]; then
  echo "Running Ktlint..."
  echo "$MODIFIED_FILES" | xargs ./gradlew ktlintCheck
else
  echo "Any files detected"
fi

Theoretically, this script should get the changed files and run the ./gradlew ktlintCheck over them but is running over the project. Does somebody know how to fix it?

Are you sure that the Gradle task takes a list of files? The documentation does not indicate that it does. Have you tried using ktlint itself?

Actually, I am not sure about that. I'm considering changing my approach to use the Ktlint as you suggested... I am really blocked with this implementation.

Use an array for the names instead of a string
